# DNT cabins near the Trondheim-Bergen bus road

Tags: accommodation, buses, norway

I am planning to do some hiking in West Norway where I've never been before. The car rental being a bit too expensive for my budget, I was planning on taking the bus from Trondheim to Bergen (bus #431 on [this page](http://bestilling.nor-way.no/NBEIIS/Search/SearchMap.aspx?Language=e&Product=P1)), and stop between these towns several times so that I can spend a few days hiking, spending nights in self-service DNT cabins.

However, I didn't find easily-accessible DNT cabins when coming from bus stops. Are there some bus shuttles available ? I didn't find this kind of information when looking at the cabins' details pages.

Surely I'm not the first tourist to encounter this situation, how do people without a car manage to reach these DNT cabins ?

Comment: Have you figured this out? Have you taken the trip already? You have to walk a few hours to reach many of the DNT cabins, there are a lot that doesn't have a road connection. What's your definition of easily accessible? Bus stop by the cabin, less than one hour walk, less than 4 hours walk..? At what time of the year are you going (unless you've already taken the trip)?

Comment: Also, what's a DNT cabin?

Comment: @MarkMayo : DNT cabins are accomodation places in Norway which are located outside of cities, mostly in the mountains or near fjords. They can be either staffed, with a self-service or with no service at all. Details on the Norwegian Treeking Association website : [here](http://english.turistforeningen.no/index.php?fo_id=3610)

Comment: @BrunoPérel cool, today I learned.  Felt it might be handy for others to know what they were too.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this question? If so, I'll try to give you a thorough answer if you answer the questions in my previous comment =) Have you taken the trip already? Which cabins did you visit?

Comment: @Robert P. : Sorry, forgot to answer. I indeed did the trip already, in early September. Eventually I didn't use DNT cabins as it seemed too risky to use them without having a lot of information. I considered 2 hours of walk maximum from a bus stop to be reasonable (then walking to some other one the next day), but the main problem I was scared about was the possibility of some weather hazard : if the DNT cabin is located in the mountains I don't know where I could sleep. I would however be interested about your knowledge on the topic as I may come back to Norway for a more trek-oriented trip.

Comment: I see, then I'll come back with an answer at a later time, as you're not in a rush... Hope you had a nice trip!

Comment: @StewieGriffin you could still answer this :)

Comment: @chx: I will answer this, as well as several EE questions I've promised answers to when I get ahead of things and get some spare spare time. (Un?)fortunately, a lot of my spare time is spent other places than SE at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that most of the Norwegian mountain hiking area is a high plateau rather than an alpine range, and getting onto the plateau and into the hut network from the west can be arduous. Once you're up, however, you can hut-to-hut more easily.

You might like to look at GRINDEFLETHYTTA. Accessible from the Bergen-Trondheim road before it drops to Gudvangen. (I am sorry that I don't have my maps with me here, and that I have lived in Bergen for decades but am less well acquainted with the highway north of the Sognefjord.)

Comment: Grindeflet is a nice cabin, but a few things to keep in mind. It's unstaffed, meaning you might need the DNT key to get in. All members of DNT can buy this key, and it works for almost all of the self service cabins. Also, if you go there before mid july you may encounter quite some snow. I was there in early july, and there was only one couple that had been there before us that summer.